# Install magento 2 on local using console ( CLI )

Tags: php, magento2

i've tried to install magento localy but i got time limit error.
for some reason i can't change my php timelimit. is theres a way to install it using console (CLI)?

Comment: this is in the docs of magento 2 ...

Comment: can you give an example plz ?

Comment: my ddg search: magento2 installtion through command line first result: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli.html

Comment: all they said is : php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento <command name>, but no installing instructions, if you can provide me with more details plz ?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom - there's a link to the next chapter: `Get started with the command-line installation`

Comment: Here is all of params https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commande to uninstall Magento 2

```
php bin/magento setup:uninstall
```

The commande to install Magento 2

```
php bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://<url_magento>/ \
--db-host=<database_hostname> \
--db-name=<database_name> \
--db-user=<database_user> \
--db-password=<database_password> \
--admin-firstname=<admin_firstname> \
--admin-lastname=<admin_lastname> \
--admin-email=<admin_email> \
--admin-user=<admin_username> \
--admin-password=<admin_password> \
--language=<default_language_code> \
--currency=<default_currency> \
--timezone=<default_timezone> \
--backend-frontname=<admin_link>
```